# How to retrieve object stored in map value?

Tags: java, dictionary

```
Set<Entry<Integer, InventoryStock>> inventoryData=
Set<Map.Entry<Integer,InventoryStock>>) ois.readObject(); 
 for( Entry<Integer, InventoryStock> list:inventoryData) {
             for(InventoryStock stock:list) 
            if(stock!=null){
            System.out.println("Item id" + stock.getItemID()+"  "+stock);
             map.putIfAbsent(stock.getItemID(), stock);
              }
```

I am picking `inventoryData` set from a `.ser` file and now I need to access the values of the map (which are `inventorystock` objects) and I need to assign it to another map. It is an showing error at the second enhanced for loop:

> error: Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable in 2nd for loop

Please help me fix this code!

Comment: the variable `list` is of type `Entry<Integer, InventoryStock>`. An entry has a key (en Integer, here) and a value (an InventoryStock, here). You can't iterate over an entry.

Answer (score 1):

You can not iterate an `Entry`. An `Entry` is a pair of `(key, value)`, so to get the (singular) `InventoryStock` from the `Entry`, you have to use `getValue`.

```
for( Entry<Integer, InventoryStock> entry : inventoryData) {
    InventoryStock stock = entry.getValue();
    if (stock != null) {
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable

```
list
```

(the name is misleading in this case) is no container - you cannot iterate through it.
Try something like

```
for( Entry<Integer, InventoryStock> listItem:inventoryData) {
  InventoryStock myStock = listItem.getValue();
  if (...) {
    //
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Entry<Integer, InventoryStock>
```

is just pair of (key, value) and is not iterable. If your `InventoryStock` is iterable and you want to iterate over it you have to get it **from** your entry first. `InventoryStock` is a value so use method `entry.getValue()` to get it:

```
for( Entry<Integer, InventoryStock> entry :inventoryData) {
             for(InventoryStock stock: entry.getValue())
```